# Is it possible to ask for user input with a 'trailing prompt', e.g `Enter your answer as a percentage: <user input> %`?

Tags: python

I was wondering if it was possible to ask for input in between the output?

E.g., I want to be able to prompt the user like so:

```
Enter your answer as a percentage: <user input> %
```

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: Dunno, have you tried anything?

Comment: And yes, it's possible, but you might need a third party library for it and it might not be portable across OSes or even shells.

Comment: You can take a look at the [curses](https://docs.python.org/3/library/curses.html) module; but it's probably a bit overkill for this sort of task, there doesn't seem to be any easy ways to do accomplish what you're looking for though.